# @Sql script does not run for @test when adding @TestExecutionListeners to test suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, junit4

I am testing a Spring Batch ItemProcessor which reads fetches a value from DB.

As suggested on [Testing Step-Scoped Components](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#d5e3531) page, I add **@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })** to the test suite annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/context-configuration.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CustomItemProcessorTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessor<InputClass, OutputClass> customItemProcessor;

    @Test
    @Sql(scripts = {"insertDataToBeRetrievedByCustomItemProcessor.sql" }, 
            config = @SqlConfig(dataSource = "dataSource"))
    public void assertThatCustomItemProcessorProcessorIsRetrievingStillBirthSasEtlObject() throws Exception 
    {
        OutputClass outputObject = customItemProcessor.process(inputClassObject);
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that the above line: **@TestExecutionListeners...** is preventing the @Sql(scripts =... command from executing.

The customItemProcessor is reading values from the database with ease.

Why is the above annotation preventing the @Sql scripts from running and how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try to add `MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS` as mergeMode to the test execution listener?

Comment: Hi Roman, your suggestion solved my problem. If you add it as an answer, I will mark it as the right answer and also upvote it. Many thanks, Lucas

Answer (score 4):

when you use the annotation *TestExecutionListeners*, you overdrive the default configuration
to get your sql script to be execute, you need to add this listener *SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener*

```java
@TestExecutionListeners( { 
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class, 
  SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener 
})
```